# Cpu core number != CPU_allows , why?

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture, proc, cpu-cores

```
 **cpu :** E5-2630L * 2 
 **os :** Linux CentOS 6.3
```

*physical core :* 12
*logical core :* 24 (grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo, by hyper threading)

```
 E5-2630L has 6 cores, so total 24. (6*2*2)
 but /proc/pid/status is

  - Cpus_allowed:   ffffffff,ffffffff
  - Cpus_allowed_list:      0-63
```

cpu has `24` logical cores, but why cpu_allowed is `64`?

Comment: I think BTW: you are offtopic with this question here, it is more a serverfault question (but the Downvote is not from me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the default, it just means there is no further restriction (besides the available hardware). I think the mask is a multiple of 32bit, but it always starts with 2 times that.